# I want to retrieve Product information

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve All Add_product data using current user uid How is it possible.

My code return only loading widget because my query is incorrect. How can I write my query in a correct way?

My database:

[image: 1][image: 2][image: 3]

My code

```
StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup("Add_product").where("id",isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).snapshots(),
                builder:(BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>snapshot){
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(child: LoadingAnimationWidget.staggeredDotsWave(color: Colors.red, size: 10));
                  }

      `            return Container(
                   
                          child: InkWell(
                            child: Card(
                              elevation:5,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
                                    child: Image.network(snapshot.data!.docs[index]["url"],width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*.49,height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.17 ,),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 7,),
                                  Text(
                                    snapshot.data!.docs[index]["product_name"],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                    ),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 4),
               
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                }
            ),
```

Comment: Your database structure is quite messy, I think you should consider changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Add_product").snapshots(),
                builder:(BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>snapshot){
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(child: LoadingAnimationWidget.staggeredDotsWave(color: Colors.red, size: 10));
                  }

      `            return Container(
                   
                          child: InkWell(
                            child: Card(
                              elevation:5,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
                                    child: Image.network(snapshot.data!.docs[index]["url"],width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*.49,height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.17 ,),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 7,),
                                  Text(
                                    snapshot.data!.docs[index]["product_name"],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                    ),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 4),
               
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                }
            ),
```

If you also need user id, you can get the userId first and store it into the variable and pass that variable into `where`

Comment: But i want to retrieve all data of Add product which include sub collections.

Answer (score 0):

In my perspective the `firebase` structure which you are following is not recommended, consider changing it.

To answer your question, you can try:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore
                  .instance.
                  .collection('Add_product')
                  .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                  .collection('Add_product')
                  .snapshots(), 
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Something went wrong');
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Text("Loading");
            }
            return ListView(
                children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              Map<String, dynamic> data =
                  document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(data['product_name']), // Should print "Cloth"
              );
            }).toList());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```